# django - I don't see anything from database when i want to display the contents on cards/index page

Tags: python, html, css, django, database

django - I don't see anything from database when i want to display the contents on cards/index page. in the admin section it's working but here not working. BTW sorry my bad communication

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.all_id_cards),
 ]
```

**views.py**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from .models import IdCard

def all_id_cards(request):
    cards = IdCard.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'cards/cards_index.html', { 'cards': cards })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class IdCard(models.Model):
   emp_id = models.CharField(max_length=12)
   emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   emp_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   emp_telephone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
   emp_email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   emp_generation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   emp_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.emp_name
```

**cards_index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Identity Cards</h1>
        <div class="identitycards">
            {% for cards in cards %}
                <div class="identitycard">
                    <p>{{ IdCard.emp_name }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. you iterate over the items with `{% for cards in cards %}`, so the *iterator* has the same name as the collection. Although it *might* work, it is better to avoid that, since it can result in unpredictable behavior; and
2. you render the content with `{{ IdCard.emp_name }}`. `IdCard` is not passed to the rendering, but anyway, you need to use `card`, so `{{ card.emp_name }}`.

If we fix the two issues we get as template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Homepage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Identity Cards</h1>
        <div class="identitycards">
            {% for card in cards %}
                <div class="identitycard">
                    <p>{{ card.emp_name }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, basically same answer I wrote. I'm going to delete mine, you've been faster!

Comment: i appreciate your helping. Thank you so much.